# How to use debounce hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function useDebounce(text: string, delay: number) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setValue(text);
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [text, delay]);
  return value;
}
```

I used to make and use `useDebounce` hook.
However, using `useDebounce` in resize event has some problems.
The `useDebounce hook` must run at the top of the component because it uses useEffect inside.
However, the resize function is set to run on useEffect as shown below.

Also, the above code takes value as a factor, but I think we need to receive it as callback to use the below code.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      if (liRef.current) setWidth(liRef.current.clientWidth);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handler);
  }, []);
```

How do I use the above code to utilize the existing useDebounce?

Comment: You don't need a hook to debounce an event handler. Just debounce the function directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think rather than implementing debounce through `useEffect`, it would be better to implement the debounce logic as a function.

`UseEffect` is executed when the states referenced by `deps` change. In other words, since it is a logic that can be missed if you only follow the execution flow, it is difficult to figure out which flow this `useEffect` was derived from when performing maintenance later, and it can be difficult to debug.

**Example**

`Custom Debounce`

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}
```

```js
function saveInput() {
  console.log('Saving data');
}
const processChange = debounce(() => saveInput());

<input type="text" onkeyup="processChange()" />
```

And if you use `lodash`, you can just import to use it.

`Lodash Debounce`

```js
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
```

```js
const debounceOnChange = debounce(() => {
  console.log("This is a debounce function");
}, 500);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you directly use debounced function inside a react component, it will not work, since a new function will be created on each render, Instead, you can use this `useDebounce` hook:

```js
function useDebounce(callback, delay) {
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(callback)
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback
  })
  return React.useMemo(
    () => debounce((...args) => callbackRef.current(...args), delay),
    [delay],
  )
}
```

`useRef` makes sure that it is the same function provided last time, and `useLayoutEffect` makes sure on each render, the reference to function gets updated.

For more info on this, see ['The Latest Ref' pattern in React](https://epicreact.dev/the-latest-ref-pattern-in-react/)

Comment: What is the `debounce()` function called in the `useMemo()`?